# gnuplottex and shell-escape

Tags: texworks, shell-escape, gnuplottex

I am trying to get `gnuplottex` running in this MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage{gnuplottex}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}%
\centering%
\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=epslatex]
plot sin(x) w l
\end{gnuplot}
\caption{This is a simple example using the epslatex-terminal.}%
\end{figure}%

\end{document}
```

The figure environment appears, however no plot!

I already included a new typesetting option...

[image: typesetting option]

...and the log file says `\write18 enabled` in the third line.

Nonetheless, the log file says:

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014/W32TeX)
>   (preloaded format=pdflatex 2014.9.22)  18 FEB 2016 12:01 
>   entering extended mode 
>   \write18 enabled.
>
> [...]
>
> Package gnuplottex Warning: Shell escape not enabled.
>   (gnuplottex) You'll need to convert the graphs yourself.
>
> [...]
>
> Package gnuplottex Warning: Please convert gnuplot-gnuplottex-fig1.gnuplot manually
>
> [...]

The gnuplot source file is created.
I'm using TeX Live 2014, TeXworks, Windows 7 (64bit) and gnuplot 5.0 (path variable is set - gnuplot is launched when typing `gnuplot` into the console).

---

EDIT: I'm somewhat confused about how to use the `\gnuplotexe` in order to directly point to the `gnuplot` executable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*update after exchanges with OP in comments*)

Reading through `gnuplottex` source, it appears it tests if `-shell-escape` is enabled via first creating a temporary file. For this it uses unix commands, except under option `miktex`. I thus suggest to try using that option too, despite the fact you are not under MikTeX. Fingers crossed ...

(*notice though that under that option `gnuplottex` sets to true `\ifmiktex` boolean, with global scope*)

---

Original answer:

Only to confirm it works with shell-escape enabled. As I am not on Windows I can't help more...

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage{gnuplottex}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=epslatex]
plot sin(x) w l
\end{gnuplot}
\caption{This is a simple example using the epslatex-terminal.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: This is depressing me... :P

Comment: hmm...  I don't have time now but package gnuplottex has some strange check of its own to test if shell-escape works. Appears to me this is using `unix/linux` commands which may not work on windows.

Comment: I'm sure it works on windows... there is even a `miktex` option, and this is a pure Windows distribution, if I am right.

Comment: doesn't it need something called `cygwin` ?

Comment: It's not listed in the requirements section of the `gnuplottex` documentation...

Comment: I am on TL2015, but tried TL2014 and it works too. And TL2013 and TL2012 too. I know I am depressing you ;-) Don't despair, surely some Windows expert will see your question. But most are on MikTeX I think.

Comment: :-) Maybe your ... amazingly depressing results will help identifying the problem. :D

Comment: ah ok wait I see some `\ifmiktex` conditionals in gnuplottex. In these branches gnuplottex uses windows command, else unix commands. Have you tried loading it with option `[miktex]` ?

Comment: Superman/woman, make this an answer...-- This option should be called `windows` not `miktex`!! And I even tried to set that option once and it didn't work (maybe the shell-escape slipped out in this test case!). Thank you!

Comment: Here it worked without any problem on Windows by
`\usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex}`
Please use [miktex] option even in TeX Live on Windows.
I think the option name is not good.

Comment: @AkiraKakuto Actually, the way of testing the shell escape is not good...